# How to get data from referenced table doing order by only on the first matching referencing value from referencing table?

Tags: sql

I have two tables project and code. Codes table has reference of project table with one to many relationship from project to codes. Now my requirement is to get all the project data order by the label of only first record in codes table for that project

For eg if my project table has following data:

```
PROJECT_ID  PROJECT_NAME    PROJECT_TYPE
1           a               test1
2           b               test2
```

And codes table has below mentioned data where project_id is foreign key then I should get project id 2 first and 1 later as for project id the first mapping value contains label d and for project id 2 it's a. I am not able to figure out solution for this.

```
ID  PROJECT_ID  LABEL
1      1         d
2      1         b
3      1         c
4      2         a
```

Desired output

```
PROJECT_ID  PROJECT_NAME    PROJECT_TYPE
    2           b               test2
    1           a               test1
```

Comment: "one too many relationship..."   : )

Comment: @TabAlleman yes

Comment: Can you share a sample of your desired output?

Comment: @vivkumar Did any answer solve your problem? If it didn't, indicate why, and try to clarify the question. If it did, consider accepting an answer [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @zm I will surely let u know the results. I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your phrase "first matching" is ambiguous--it could refer to the ordering by `LABEL` or by `ID` in your codes table.  Assuming the first alternative, ordering by label, then something like the following should produce the project data in the desired order.

```
select   p.*
from     project as p
         inner join (
           select   project_id, min(label) as lbl
           from     code
           group by project_id
           ) as c on c.project_id=p.project_id
order by c.lbl;
```

If you need to order by `ID` instead, just modify the subquery and the `ORDER BY` clause correspondingly.

Comment: Join should be based on project I'd but order by should be on label. But order by should be only on first matching record in codes table. Let me know if there is any issue in.understamding the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no aggregate function to match the first occurrence, you need to make two joins: first to find code id of the first occurrence, and then another one to get the label value for that occurrence so you can properly order:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PROJECT p
JOIN (SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, PROJECT_ID
      FROM code 
      GROUP BY PROJECT_ID) AS findFirst
      ON findFirst.PROJECT_ID = p.PROJECT_ID
JOIN code c ON findFirst.ID = c.ID
ORDER BY c.LABEL
```